# Identify AWS service from Interface Internal IP in VPC Flowlogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I am reading AWS VPC Flowlogs data (published to S3) which has internal IP of interfaces.

We can create flow logs for network interfaces that are created by other AWS services, such as:

- Elastic Load Balancing
- Amazon RDS
- Amazon ElastiCache
- Amazon Redshift
- Amazon WorkSpaces
- NAT gateways
- Transit gateways
  ...etc.

How can we get type of service used in Flowlog record?

In `describe-network-interfaces` response

```
"InterfaceType": "interface",
            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
            "MacAddress": "0e:fa:f9:2d:95:8e",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-02eb12a4080c84b00",
            "OwnerId": "123412341234",
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-3-1-44.ec2.internal",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.3.1.44",
```

I thought to use `PrivateDnsName` suffix but it takes the form **ip-private-ipv4-address.ec2.internal** for the **us-east-1** Region, and **ip-private-ipv4-address.region.compute.internal** for other Regions and it looks it is same for all aws services.

Is there any way to get AWS service type from private IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating flows logs you can use a custom format (below is all fields)

`${dstaddr} ${dstport} ${end} ${flow-direction} ${instance-id} ${interface-id} ${log-status} ${packets} ${pkt-dst-aws-service} ${pkt-dstaddr} ${pkt-src-aws-service} ${pkt-srcaddr} ${protocol} ${region} ${srcaddr} ${srcport} ${start} ${sublocation-id} ${sublocation-type} ${subnet-id} ${tcp-flags} ${traffic-path} ${type} ${version} ${vpc-id}`

out of these 2 fields,
`${pkt-src-aws-service} ${pkt-dst-aws-service}` are of yours interest which provides AWS services refer this aws [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html)

I verified these with s3 when ec2 communicates with s3 we get the service tag s3 with the relevant flow

Comment: When this question was asked, default format was used. These fields are introduced in AWS flowlogs v5.  It is good information for visiting users.